# how can i create an java aws lambda function using the aws cli?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

```
aws lambda create-function --function-name CliTestFun 
--runtime java8 --region ap-south-1 
--role arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/aws-lambda-execution-role 
--handler com.example.demo.Search::handleRequest
```

Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "Code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the code/zip to the lambda with --zip-file option.

```
--zip-file fileb://yourJavaCode.zip
```

You can create the zip manually or using build tools like maven/gradle. Here is the link to learn more about packaging your java code for the lambda

[Creating a ZIP Deployment Package for a Java Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/create-deployment-pkg-zip-java.html)

Comment: Hi @Juned Ahsan your answer helped me to create a deployable zip file from the maven project, now I am able to create a function from CLI. I have 1 more question that  1)after creating the function every event is adding to that function like EC2,iot and so on... how can i ignore those?
thanks Juned

Comment: @SainathPabba Glad to know that it helped you. I will encourage you to put another question on SO with your new problem so that you get better attention from all the users.